# Firebase real time database high consumption of data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm the only real  user (testing for now) for my database and here is my data downloaded from my database since I set FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);

The 12 marth (RED LINES) - *About 3MB/day*

[image]

And here is the size of my database : *Which is about 80ko.*

[image]

The data that I have access to from my account is about 1/4 so 20ko.

Since I used FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);, I don't really understand how could I download about 150 times in one day all of the data that I have acces to. And I don't really send much and delete much.

So how comes this big consumption and how can I solve this? I thought about using a SQL internal database but I don't see the point since firebase can store all of my data in my disk memory easily. More, I think that in order to check the downloaded data the listener still check in everydata if something has changed... so I don't really think it would help.

Does FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true) doesn't really reduce the cunsomption and still download what's being previsouly downloaded?

If one user uses about 2 MB/day, it would be 1GB/500users => 1$ which is pretty expensive...

What should I do ?

EDIT :

I have just made the test. I cleaned all storage of the application and downloaded all of the data that I have accessed to (about 20ko)

Here is the result  :

[image]

393ko... it's very weird. And then I checked again the data in the graphic and today I have downloaded 1 MB.

[image]

I don't see any explanation... The only one is see is that by example I don't always use the same reference when I try to look for the same thing in the database. 
By example in one activity if I need to get the username of a user I use

this :

```
Private DatabaseReference UserRef;
UserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");




UserRef.child(iD).child("name").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            String name = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString(); //do some with name

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

And in the other activity I would use the same function but I would create a another reference on it. Maybe it does make a difference and maybe it downloads twice the data instead of one because firebase doesn't know that I'm looking for the same data as I use a other variable name for reference.

Comment: I'm quite doubtful for `setPersistenceEnabled(true)` being the cause of additional network traffic, since its only purpose is to store data on cache memory for offline capabilities. In addition, your graph is quite inconclusive (pretty "jumpy"), and I can't tell what was the previous consumption before enabling the persistence. If you could provide a before/after experiment, it would be great. You should also try making it "fair" - meaning same usage every day.

Comment: Before the red lines a didn't enable the persistence and after the red lines I enabled it. As you can see the difference is not very big. And yes I will try to do that but still I dont see how the amount of downloaded data could be that important comparing to the size of the database

Comment: Hi, I've simply used the application without doing too much things. And since yesterday my "Users Memory" has grown to 6.5Mo. Which is only firebase database. This is very weird because the database still weight 100ko...
So the downloaded data that I see on the graph are true, but I have no idea where they come from. Let me explain : As you can check on the edit post, I cleared all data and downloaded again. After the download I had about 300ko in user data (which is still not normal). And know it's 6.5MB as I said but I didn't download more data (maybe couple of messages but it's nothing)